# PHP to MS SQL Server 2012 sqlsrv_get_field invalid parameter error

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I have a very simple communication between MS SQL Server 2012 and PHP 5.6.20 used on an XAMP server. I have made a connection with the database and execute a query with no problem, but when I try to display the contents of the database in the browser using echo, I get this error:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -14 [code] => -14 [2] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_get_field. [message] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_get_field. ) )
```

Below is the code itself:

```
<?php
$servername = "name";
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($servername); // working fine

$do = "USE hi; SELECT * FROM oh;"; // correct query
$stmt = sqlsrv_query ($conn, $do); // query executes


// now I have no idea what is really happening

sqlsrv_fetch ($stmt);
$try = sqlsrv_get_field ($stmt, 0);

if( $try === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true ));
}
echo $try;
sqlsrv_close ($conn);
?>
```

I have written the code with help from other sources (including questions previously asked here) but I do not know how right it is. Is this how one views the rows in a database the same way using one does using a "SELECT * FROM table" statement or is there a better way? And why am I getting an error with sqlsrv_get_field() if the connection is working and the 0 is there? (it should be 0 shouldn't it?)

Comment: Are you sure your query is working; you don't seem to be doing any checks to test that it is or not. If `$stmt` is `false` (the value returned when a query cannot be completed) it would cause [`sqlsrv_get_field`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-get-field.php) to return `false`, as the first parameter expects a `resource`.

Comment: Yes the query is working. I checked on my computer but removed the check in the code I uploaded. It was returning true.